# How do you get stereo_image_proc to include a frame_id so that rviz will accept the point cloud messages?

Tags: rviz, pcl, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running stereo_image_proc, I'm attempting to view the point cloud data with `rviz`. However `rviz` complains and throws out the messages sayin "`MessageFilter [target=/ ]: Discarding message from [/stereo_image_proc] due to empty frame_id`".

I can find no reference to `frame_id` in `stereo_image_proc`, and I've tried fiddling with the fixed frame parameters in `rviz` to no avail.

Am I missing something obvious?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9840/how-do-you-get-stereo_image_proc-to-include-a-frame_id-so-that-rviz-will-accept-the-point-cloud-messages?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that `stereo_image_proc` simply forwards the header info it finds in the `camera_info` message it gets from the left camera. If your camera info manager is not publishing a `frame_id` with in the `camera_info` message, neither will `stereo_image_proc` and you won't be able to visualize with rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3